Flutter web clears the navigation stack except the current screen using go_router
Whenever I refresh the screen which is above another screens all below screens are disposed in web using go_router with context.pushNamed.
I tried html.window.onBeforeUnload.listen((event) async{ // do something }); in order to push the lost screens but it didn't work.
I've tried using getX to handle the navigation, but it didn't work either.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
